# Warning: Input is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled

Tags: reactjs

## **Correct way to implement the react reactstrap Input type checkbox component**

I have been having some trouble to implement the reacstrap input type checkbox component, i do not know if i'm doing something wrong in the implementation, but the browser is displaying me an error when i set a state to get the input checked value.

## **error**

```
Warning: Input is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. 
Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). 
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the 
component.
```

I read about the using of uncontrolled component and controlled component. I tried to use the ref property, but I still do not find the way to solve this. I'll appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks

> ### libraries versión
>
> - react`#15.6.1`
> - reactstrap `#4.8.0`
> - components: `<Input type="checkbox" />`
> - browser: `Chrome`

**This is a link with only the react component class code**

> [gist code link](https://gist.github.com/CLenon/40a818d75f7cf82792a23e8ef0467cdc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are using an undefined state to load the value of the `<Input>` component.

For example if you initialize state like this:

`this.state = { person: {} };`

And your input is:

`<Input value={this.state.person.first} name="first" onChange={this.handleChange}/>`

When your component is initializing it will be of value `undefined` e.g. `<Input value={undefined}/>` thus you will move from controlled state to an uncontrolled state.

**Here is a simple fix:**

`<Input value={this.state.person.first||''} name="first" onChange={this.handleChange}/>`